# Parsing JSON using Groovy where array and multiple objects have no name to get list

Tags: json, groovy

new to groovy and coding in general. Trying to do the following: 
(I have looked at many previous Q&As in stackoverflow but none of the solutions I found seem to work)

I have the following JSON from which I need to get a list/string of supplier names i.e. output should be something like : "supplier 1, supplier 2, supplier 3"

```
[
   {
       "id":217564,
       "created-at":"2020-01-22T08:59:57+00:00",
       "state":"submitted",
       "supplier":
       {
          "name":"supplier 1"
       }
    },
    {
       "id":217565,
       "created-at":"2020-01-22T09:00:00+00:00",
       "state":"submitted",
       "supplier":
       {
          "name":"supplier 2"
       }
    },
    {
       "id":217566,
       "created-at":"2020-01-22T09:00:48+00:00",
       "state":"submitted",
       "supplier": 
       {
          "name":"supplier 3"
       }
    }
]
```

I used the following groovy script to print out all the supplier names in a list:

```
import groovy.json.*;

@CustomScriptAction(
    input = ['json_response'],
    output = 'suppliers'
)
def CustomScriptAction14()
{
    def object = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json_response.toString())
    def suppliers = "No suppliers"

if(object != null && !object.isEmpty())
{
    for(def i =0; i<object.size();i++)
{
    suppliers = RString.of(object[i].'supplier'.name.toString());

}
}
return suppliers
}
```

I got the output: "supplier 3"

The issue is that this script is only giving me the last supplier in the loop instead of iterating through the entire loop and printing out all the suppliers. So I tried a different script:

```
import groovy.json.*;

@CustomScriptAction(
    input = ['json_response'],
    output = 'suppliers'
)
def CustomScriptAction14()
{
    def object = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json_response)
    def suppliers = object.findAll { it.value instanceof List }
        .values()
        .flatten()
        .collect { [it.'supplier'.'name'] }
}
return suppliers
```

But with this I get a blank response.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well this ended up working:

```
import groovy.json.*;

@CustomScriptAction(
    input = ['json_response'],
    output = 'suppliers'
)


def customScript()
{

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(json_response.toString())
suppliers = RString.of(object.'supplier'.'name'.toString())

}
```